# Using Case When in a psql insert

Tags: sql, insert, case, psql

this is the error I'm getting

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "Start_Date"
LINE 8:         'Start_Date'=(CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT("End_Date") FR...
```

And this is my insert command, I'm trying to check if there are 3 end dates from exhibits that come after the current date, and if there are then I want the start date to be 5 days after the earliest one, otherwise I was to make the start date 2016/05/19

```
INSERT INTO Exhibits (
        "Name",
        "Start_Date",
        "End_Date",
        "Description")
SELECT
        'Name'='Modern America and the Contemporary World',
        'Start_Date'=(CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT("End_Date") FROM exhibits where
"End_Date">CURRENT_DATE) >= 3 THEN (select Min("End_Date")+5 FROM exhibits
where "End_Date">CURRENT_DATE) ELSE '2016/05/19' END),
        'End_Date'='2017/01/10',
        'Description'='lolololololololol'
;
```

Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't specify the columns in the `select`.  Try removing those:

```
INSERT INTO Exhibits (
        "Name",
        "Start_Date",
        "End_Date",
        "Description")
SELECT
        'Modern America and the Contemporary World',
        CASE WHEN (
                SELECT COUNT(End_Date) 
                FROM exhibits 
                WHERE End_Date>CURRENT_DATE) >= 3 
             THEN (
                SELECT Min("End_Date")+5 
                FROM exhibits
                WHERE End_Date>CURRENT_DATE) 
             ELSE '2016/05/19' END,
        '2017/01/10',
        'lolololololololol'
;
```